# Make table data corners touch

Tags: html, css, html-table, chess

I'm trying to make a chess board and am having a slight issue with the squares' appearances. The checkerboard color scheme is working correctly but for some reason the corners of each square don't seem to be touching.

Here's a snippet of the code I have for 2 rows, where each data entry either belongs to a class "light" or "dark":

```
<tr><td id="1"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="2"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="3"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="4"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="5"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="6"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="7"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="8"><span class="light"></span></td></tr>

<tr><td id="9"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="10"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="11"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="12"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="13"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="14"><span class="dark"></span></td><td id="15"><span class="light"></span></td><td id="16"><span class="dark"></span></td></tr>
```

My CSS code looks like this:

```
td {
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
}
table{
    border:2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}    
span{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}    
.light{
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
}    
.dark{
    background-color: #8B4513;
}
```

Which produces a table that looks like this:

[image]

I was wondering if there's any way to clean up the look of the table, mainly to make the corners of each color touch one another.

Answer (score 1):

Please add cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" to the table element, for you to remove extra space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Try making cellspacing and cellpadding equal to 0. Also make the border collapse

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx1bp2nc/)

trick is this CSS

```
td {
  height:60px;
  width:60px;
  padding:0px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```